# Is there any alternative to Wronskian?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Calculating a Wronskian is a very painful process, especially for higher order differential equations. Actually, I'm trying to solve a **4th order non-homogeneous linear differential equation**. Consider the equation given below, for example,
$$    y'''' - u^4y = e^{ux}, \quad \text{where $u > 0$ is a constant.} $$

I got general solution,

$$    y = C_1.e^{ux} + C_2.e^{-ux} + C_3.cos(ux) + C_4.sin(ux)$$

to homogeneous equation,

$$    y'''' - u^4y = 0, \quad \text{where $u > 0$ is a constant.} $$

As we can see, we got four functions, namely, $f1...f4$, to calculate Wronskian. Here I ended up solving a $4X4$ determinant.

Is there any alternative?

**Note:** *I solved it using **undeteremined coefficient**, $y_p = x.p.e^{ux}$. Still your answers were helpful. Thanks.*

Comment: Maybe having your OE here, could help us to solve the original OE. Not to search an alternative approach.

Comment: If you post the DEQ, we can take a look and make recommendations. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: I updated my question to add an example equation.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari:  Is the OE $y^{(4)}-C^4y=\text{e}^{Cx}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to find a particular solution to $y^{(4)}-u^4y=e^{ux}$, so you can focus on the linear equation $y^{(4)}-u^4y=0$.

If $X=(y''',y'',y',y)$, then $X'=AX$ with $A=\left( \begin{array}{cccc} 0&0&0&u^4 \\ 1 & 0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0  \end{array} \right)$. You only have to compute $\exp(A)$ (notice that $A^4= u^4 \operatorname{Id}$).

Comment: Thanks Seirios. Btw, what this method is called? So, I can read on this method to understand it better.

Comment: @AdeelAnsari: I don't know whether this method has a name; but it is a general argument to transform a DE of order $n$ to a DE of order 1.

Comment: @Seirios: What's the connection between $\exp(A)$ and the Wronskian?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Before OP's edition, the question seemed to be to solve the differential equation, and not really to find the wronskian. So I gave a possible solution. But it is not difficult to find the wronskian with a basis of solutions.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to approach it.

For example, for the homogeneous case, we could have written the characteristic equation as:

$$m^4 -u^4 = 0$$

This leads to the four roots $\pm u$ and $\pm iu$.

From that knowledge, we can write the solution as:

$$y_H = y = C_1.e^{ux} + C_2.e^{-ux} + C_3.\cos ux + C_4.\sin ux$$

Now, we need only deal with the particular solution, and we see that one of the roots is coincident with the particular (RHS) function, so there are pretty straightforward ways to deal with that.

Another approach is to linearize the system and write it as $X' = AX$ as was shown in another answer.

Here, you will find the same roots to the characteristic polynomial, can diagnoalize the system (if it is diagonalizable) and write the exponential solution for that matrix.

There are other ways too, but these two are worth exploring.

Comment: Honestly, I wanted to do as you noted, but, I saw @Seirios's approach and didn't do that. +10

Comment: Thank you my friend - I thought it was also important to give options and I think he will appreciate how much easier the characteristic approach was. I think the Pollard/Tennabaum book you mentioned would be perfect to recommend! Regards

Comment: Good optional approaches! +1

Comment: @amWhy: I thought it was important to point those out because that approach is sometimes brutal! :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given an $n$-th order linear **homogeneous** differential equation
$$y^{(n)} +p_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)} +\ldots + p_1(x) y'+ p_0(x) y=0\tag{1}$$
the Wronskian is a quantity $t\mapsto W(t):=W[y_1,\ldots, y_n](t)$ associated to a basis ${\bf b}=(y_1,\ldots, y_n)$ of the solution space ${\cal L}$. Formally it is the determinant of the matrix formed by the jet-extensions $(y_k, y_k', \ldots, y_k^{(n-1)})$ of the basis functions. From this one can conclude that $W(\cdot)$ is multiplied with a constant factor when the basis ${\bf b}$ is replaced by some other basis ${\bf b}'$, and this in turn suggests that $W(\cdot)$ satisfies a certain linear differential equation of the form $w'= c(x) w$, where $c(x)$ can be determined directly from $(1)$. In fact [Abel's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity) says that
$$W'(x)=-p_{n-1}(x) W(x)\ .$$
In the case at hand it follows that $W(\cdot)$ is a constant. The numerical value of this constant depends on the chosen basis ${\bf b}$, and there is no simple way out of computing it, other than putting $x=0$.